# SQLite UNION not performing when one resultset is empty

Tags: java, sqlite, r-tree

I have a union in SQLite where I select data from 3 rtree's

```
CREATE TABLE monsters (id INT PRIMARY KEY, x INT, y INT, z INT, name TEXT, health INT, strength int, regen int, weapon int);
CREATE TABLE animals (id INT PRIMARY KEY, x INT, y INT, z INT, name TEXT, health INT,species int, speed int, drops int, speech int);
CREATE TABLE players (id INT PRIMARY KEY, x INT, y INT, z INT, name TEXT, health INT,uuid TEXT, stamina int, level int);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE rtreeOne USING rtree(id, startx,endx,starty,endy,startz,endz);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE rtreeTwo USING rtree(id, startx,endx,starty,endy,startz,endz);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE rtreeThree USING rtree(id, startx,endx,starty,endy,startz,endz);

CREATE TRIGGER updateOne AFTER INSERT ON monsters FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO rtreeOne (id, startx,endx,starty,endy,startz,endz) VALUES (new.id, new.x, new.x, new.y, new.y, new.z,new.z);END;

CREATE TRIGGER updateTwo AFTER INSERT ON animals FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO rtreeOne (id, startx,endx,starty,endy,startz,endz) VALUES (new.id, new.x, new.x, new.y, new.y, new.z,new.z);END;

CREATE TRIGGER updateThree AFTER INSERT ON players FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO rtreeOne (id, startx,endx,starty,endy,startz,endz) VALUES (new.id, new.x, new.x, new.y, new.y, new.z,new.z);END;

WITH one AS (SELECT id
   FROM rtreeOne
   WHERE startx > 20
     AND starty > 40
     AND startz > 11
     AND endx < 40
     AND endy < 50
     AND endz < 44),
 two AS (SELECT id
   FROM rtreeTwo
   WHERE startx > 20
     AND starty > 40
     AND startz > 11
     AND endx < 40
     AND endy < 50
     AND endz < 44),
 three AS (SELECT id
   FROM rtreeThree
   WHERE startx > 20
     AND starty > 40
     AND startz > 11
     AND endx < 40
     AND endy < 50
     AND endz < 44),
 monone AS (SELECT *
   FROM one
   JOIN monsters ON one.id=monsters.id),
 anitwo AS (SELECT *
   FROM two
   JOIN animals ON two.id=animals.id),
 playthree AS (SELECT *
   FROM three
   JOIN players ON three.id=players.id),
 living AS (
    SELECT name,
          x,
          y,
          z,
          health
   FROM monone
  UNION ALL
   SELECT SELECT name,
          x,
          y,
          z,
          health
   FROM anitwo
  UNION ALL
   SELECT name,
                x,
                y,
                z,
                health
   FROM playthree)
SELECT name,
       x,
       y,
       z,
       health
FROM living;
```

This union performs well when there are all 3 types within range. But when one type is missing in range, that resultset returns nothing and the complete union of the 3 rowsets fail and nothing gets returned, although animals and players are in the list.

How can I refactor this query so it won't kill itself if one resultset of 3 returns nothing?

Should I use a bogus join so it will always have dummy value and nulls besides it or are there better alternatives?

Comment: I believe an `OUTER JOIN` would solve your requirement.

Comment: `the complete union of the 3 column fails` ... the `UNION` operator aggregates rows _not_ columns.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I mix them up constantly in what they are called @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I was thinking the same @SubOptimal, but I was wondering if there are other tricks in sqlite for these scenario's. hence my question.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Could you please share the `CREATE` statements for the tables and R*Trees. Might not be unimportant in this case.

Comment: I've added the create statements for the R*Tree's and the triggers to populate them. I might have made a typo because i'm not at my dev pc atm, but this should do it.

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Answer (score 0):

I unwind your query a bit (hopefully I rigth understand what you want to achieve). Below query would return the combined rows for the matched `monsters`, `animals` and `players`.

```
SELECT monsters.name, monsters.x, monsters.y, monsters.z, monsters.health
  FROM rtreeOne one
  JOIN monsters ON one.id = monsters.id
  WHERE one.startx > 20
  AND one.starty > 40
  AND one.startz > 11
  AND one.endx < 40
  AND one.endy < 50
  AND one.endz < 44
union all
  SELECT animals.name, animals.x, animals.y, animals.z, animals.health
  FROM rtreeTwo two
  JOIN animals ON two.id = animals.id
  WHERE two.startx > 20
  AND two.starty > 40
  AND two.startz > 11
  AND two.endx < 40
  AND two.endy < 50
  AND two.endz < 44
union all
  SELECT players.name, players.x, players.y, players.z, players.health
  FROM rtreeThree three
  JOIN players ON one.id = players.id
  WHERE three.startx > 20
  AND three.starty > 40
  AND three.startz > 11
  AND three.endx < 40
  AND three.endy < 50
  AND three.endz < 44
```

Comment: No, this query will fail because of the rtree behaviour. Theres a reason why im using the with heh. Also this gives the same issues what if there are no players in range. THen the union will fail. Basically i want the union to succeed when one of the three or two of the three resultsets return nothing.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Ok. Now I see your point about [rtree](https://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) and my mistake.

Comment: The stupid thing is, unions don't fail on regular database queries http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5cee0/2 but in this case if one of the resultsets is empty, it simply blanks out as if there is nothing, but if I remove the part where it has no results, it returns the results... This might be an SQLite quirk though.